# Send email with Sendgrid webapi in quarkus

Tags: sendgrid, quarkus

Is there any approach on how to use sendgrid with webapi in quarkus ?
i have seen solution with SMTP

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid evangelist here.

Quarkus is new to me! However there is a guide for [using SMTP in Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/mailer) and there is documentation for [how to use SendGrid over SMTP](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api).

Alternatively, there is [documentation for using the Quarkus REST Client](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client) and you could combine that with the [SendGrid REST API](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send).

If you can install Java dependencies in Quarkus (this is a point I'm unsure on), there is a [SendGrid Java library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java) that could help.